# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected, but it works in Oracle Toad

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, oracle, exception

I'm using VS2010 and Oracle as my database in a x64 machine, but I'm having problems with my .NET code. Here it is:

It's just a function called from a webservice of a DataGrid Selecting function.

```
Public Shared Function get_lista(ByVal i_filtros As CBoletaGarantiaListafiltro, ByVal i_usuario As CUsuario, ByVal i_con As OracleConnection, ByVal i_tran As OracleTransaction, ByRef o_error As CError) As List(Of CBoletaGarantiaLista)
        Dim sql As String
        sql = " select  "
        sql = sql & " a.id_proyecto  "
        sql = sql & " ,a.id_solicitud  "
        sql = sql & " ,a.fecha_ingreso "
        sql = sql & " ,a.usuario_ingreso "
        sql = sql & " ,a.estado  "
        sql = sql & " ,a.cod_motivo  "
        sql = sql & " ,a.beneficiario  "
        sql = sql & " ,a.tipo_obra_bol  "
        sql = sql & " ,a.tipo_plazo  "
        sql = sql & " ,a.vigencia "
        sql = sql & " ,a.monto "
        sql = sql & " ,a.codigo_moneda  "
        sql = sql & " ,a.flex  "
        sql = sql & " ,a.fecha_esperada "
        sql = sql & " ,a.tomador "
        sql = sql & " ,b.sdesc tipo_obra_desc "
        sql = sql & " ,c.sdesc tipo_plazo_desc "
        sql = sql & " ,d.sdesc tomador_desc "
        sql = sql & " ,e.sdesc beneficiario_desc "
        sql = sql & " ,f.sdesc codigo_moneda_desc"
        sql = sql & " ,g.nombre nombre_proyecto"
        sql = sql & " ,a.etapa "
        sql = sql & " ,h.sdesc estado_desc "
        sql = sql & " ,a.glosa  "
        sql = sql & " ,i.nro_boleta  "
        sql = sql & "  from abd_bol_garantia a "
        sql = sql & " , abd_codigos b   "
        sql = sql & " , abd_codigos c "
        sql = sql & " , abd_codigos d "
        sql = sql & " , abd_codigos e "
        sql = sql & " , abd_monedas f "
        sql = sql & " , abd_proyectos g "
        sql = sql & " , abd_codigos h "
        sql = sql & " , abd_bol_garantia_obtencion i "
        sql = sql & " where  "
        sql = sql & "    b.tipo=65 "
        sql = sql & " and b.codigo=a.tipo_obra_bol "
        sql = sql & " and c.tipo=66 "
        sql = sql & " and c.codigo=a.tipo_plazo "
        sql = sql & " and d.tipo=67 "
        sql = sql & " and d.codigo=a.tomador "
        sql = sql & " and e.tipo=68 "
        sql = sql & " and e.codigo=a.beneficiario "
        sql = sql & " and f.ID_MONEDA=a.codigo_moneda "
        sql = sql & " and g.ID_proyecto=a.id_proyecto "
        sql = sql & " and h.tipo=71 "
        sql = sql & " and h.codigo=a.estado "
        sql = sql & " and a.id_solicitud=i.id_solicitud(+)"


        If Not i_filtros.estado Is Nothing Then
            sql = sql & " and a.estado=:estado "
        End If

        sql = sql & " and a.vigencia>=:vigencia_ini "
        sql = sql & " and a.vigencia<:vigencia_fin "

        If Not i_filtros.id_proyecto Is Nothing Then
            sql = sql & " and a.id_proyecto=:id_proyecto "
        End If

        If Not i_filtros.id_solicitud Is Nothing Then
            sql = sql & " and a.id_solicitud=:id_solicitud "
        End If

        sql = sql & " order by  a.id_solicitud "

        Dim comando As New OracleCommand(sql, i_con, i_tran)


        comando.Parameters.Add("vigencia_ini", OracleType.DateTime).Value = i_filtros.fecha_vigencia_ini.Date
        comando.Parameters.Add("vigencia_fin", OracleType.DateTime).Value = i_filtros.fecha_vigencia_fin.Date.AddDays(1)


        If Not i_filtros.estado Is Nothing Then
            comando.Parameters.Add("estado", OracleType.Int32).Value = i_filtros.estado
        End If


        If Not i_filtros.id_proyecto Is Nothing Then
            comando.Parameters.Add("id_proyecto", OracleType.Int32).Value = i_filtros.id_proyecto
        End If

        If Not i_filtros.id_solicitud Is Nothing Then
            comando.Parameters.Add("id_solicitud", OracleType.Int32).Value = i_filtros.id_solicitud
        End If


        Dim leer As OracleDataReader


        leer = comando.ExecuteReader


        Dim x_lista As New List(Of CBoletaGarantiaLista)
        While leer.Read
            Dim a As New CBoletaGarantiaLista

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(0) Then
                a.id_proyecto = leer.GetInt32(0)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(1) Then
                a.id_solicitud = leer.GetInt32(1)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(2) Then
                a.fecha_ingreso = leer.GetDateTime(2)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(3) Then
                a.usuario_ingreso = leer.GetString(3)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(4) Then
                a.estado = leer.GetInt32(4)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(5) Then
                a.cod_motivo = leer.GetInt32(5)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(6) Then
                a.beneficiario = leer.GetInt32(6)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(7) Then
                a.tipo_obra_bol = leer.GetInt32(7)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(8) Then
                a.tipo_plazo = leer.GetInt32(8)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(9) Then
                a.vigencia = leer.GetDateTime(9)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(10) Then
                a.monto = leer.GetDouble(10)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(11) Then
                a.codigo_moneda = leer.GetInt32(11)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(12) Then
                a.flex = leer.GetInt32(12)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(13) Then
                a.fecha_esperada = leer.GetDateTime(13)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(14) Then
                a.tomador = leer.GetInt32(14)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(15) Then
                a.tipo_obra_desc = leer.GetString(15)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(16) Then
                a.tipo_plazo_desc = leer.GetString(16)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(17) Then
                a.tomador_desc = leer.GetString(17)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(18) Then
                a.beneficiario_desc = leer.GetString(18)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(19) Then
                a.codigo_moneda_desc = leer.GetString(19)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(20) Then
                a.nombre_proyecto = leer.GetString(20)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(21) Then
                a.etapa = leer.GetInt32(21)

                If a.etapa = 1 Then
                    a.etapa_desc = "Aprobacion de Solicitud"
                ElseIf a.etapa = 2 Then
                    a.etapa_desc = "Entrega de Boleta"
                ElseIf a.etapa = 3 Then
                    a.etapa_desc = "Retiro de Boleta"
                ElseIf a.etapa = 4 Then
                    a.etapa_desc = "Devolucion a Tesoreria"
                End If
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(22) Then
                a.estado_desc = leer.GetString(22)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(23) Then
                a.glosa = leer.GetString(23)
            End If

            If Not leer.IsDBNull(24) Then
                a.nro_boleta = leer.GetString(24)
            End If

            x_lista.Add(a)
        End While

        leer.Close()
        Return x_lista
    End Function
```

As I try to debug the it, I keep on having the error message of :

> From keyword not found where expected

But as I tried it on Oracle Toad and SQLPLUS, it run without any error.

I'm kind of a newbie, but I shouldn't have any problem with this query...it's not so complicated, isn't it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You most likely have a formatting error.  Did you try to print out the sql string in the debugger, paste that into toad, and run it?

Comment: Yes, i tried it and works perfectly the problem is when i debug/run it on VS2010

Comment: What version of Oracle you use? First thing you should do is drop this syntax, which is not recommended by Oracle itself. A standard `inner join on...`, `left join on...`, `right join on...` recommended instead of "plus" as in `a.id_solicitud=i.id_solicitud(+)`
Also, as far as vb.net coding goes, this is disaster, you should stop this: `sql = sql & " a.id_proyecto  "` and do this: `sql = "a.id_proyecto  " & _`

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11g SE...and I also tried with outer left join instead of (+) sentence, but it makes no difference.

PS: Anyway, is there any real difference between (+) and joins?

Comment: Using(+) is not recommended. May be there is some plan compilation differences but this technology is legacy and shouldn't be used anymore. What DB connectivity you using?

Comment: Looks like interpretation issue with your DB connectivity. I would be interested to see if you insert "AS" before field aliases. Because I don't see any other reason why "From" would be not found. I know, this shouldn't be different than without "AS" but try

Answer (score 0):

This is what your first part of code should look like. Note, I may not got exact correct command object overload but the point is to assign command text later.

```
Dim static as String = "Select" & _
" a.id_proyecto" & _
", a.id_solicitud" & _
", a.fecha_ingreso" & _
", a.usuario_ingreso" & _
", a.estado" & _
", a.cod_motivo" & _
", a.beneficiario" & _
", a.tipo_obra_bol" & _
", a.tipo_plazo" & _
", a.vigencia" & _
", a.monto" & _
", a.codigo_moneda" & _
", a.flex" & _
", a.fecha_esperada" & _
", a.tomador" & _
", b.sdesc tipo_obra_desc" & _
", c.sdesc tipo_plazo_desc" & _
", d.sdesc tomador_desc" & _
", e.sdesc beneficiario_desc" & _
", f.sdesc codigo_moneda_desc" & _
", g.nombre nombre_proyecto" & _
", a.etapa" & _
", h.sdesc estado_desc" & _
", a.glosa " & _
", i.nro_boleta" & _
" From " & _
"abd_bol_garantia a inner join " & _
"abd_codigos b on b.codigo = a.tipo_obra_bol inner join " & _
"abd_codigos c on c.codigo = a.tipo_plazo inner join " & _
"abd_codigos d on d.codigo = a.tomador inner join " & _
"abd_codigos e on e.codigo = a.beneficiario inner join " & _
"abd_monedas f on f.ID_MONEDA = a.codigo_moneda inner join " & _
"abd_proyectos g on g.ID_proyecto = a.id_proyecto inner join " & _
"abd_codigos h on h.codigo = a.estado left join " & _
"abd_bol_garantia_obtencion i on a.id_solicitud = i.id_solicitud " & _
"Where " & _
"b.tipo = 65 and " & _
"c.tipo = 66 and " & _
"d.tipo = 67 and " & _
"e.tipo = 68 and " & _
"h.tipo = 71" 

dim execSql as new StringBuilder(static)
Dim comando As New OracleCommand(i_con, i_tran)

execSql.Append(" and a.vigencia >= :vigencia_ini")
execSql.Append(" and a.vigencia < :vigencia_fin")   
comando.Parameters.Add("vigencia_ini", OracleType.DateTime).Value = i_filtros.fecha_vigencia_ini.Date
comando.Parameters.Add("vigencia_fin", OracleType.DateTime).Value = i_filtros.fecha_vigencia_fin.Date.AddDays(1)    


If Not i_filtros.estado Is Nothing Then
    execSql.Append(" and a.estado = :estado")
    comando.Parameters.Add("estado", OracleType.Int32).Value = i_filtros.estado
End If

If Not i_filtros.id_proyecto Is Nothing Then
    execSql.Append(" and a.id_proyecto = :id_proyecto")
comando.Parameters.Add("id_proyecto", OracleType.Int32).Value = i_filtros.id_proyecto
End If

If Not i_filtros.id_solicitud Is Nothing Then
    execSql.Append(" and a.id_solicitud=:id_solicitud")
    comando.Parameters.Add("id_solicitud", OracleType.Int32).Value = i_filtros.id_solicitud
End If

execSql.Append(" Order By  a.id_solicitud")


comando.CommandText = execSql.ToString()
```

Comment: I took some of you reply and mixed it with my code to make it work, thanks T.S...however, it only worked after rebooting my machine, so I think it was a debugger issue. :D

Comment: the issue was that your code was filling the memory Heap. If you use mine, you will be good. Also, use inner joins, seriously :o)